# Написание плагина на Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. Есть такая необходимость, написать плагин расширений для элементора. Тестово смог сделать внутри самого dynamic-content-for-elementor поле инпут в форму и при выборе полей, мое поле появляется, все хорошо. Но имеется связь с файлами

1. autoload_static.php в нем прописано:
   'DynamicContentForElementor\Extensions\CustomFormFieldTest' => **DIR** . '/../..' . '/includes/extensions/form/test.php',
2. Extensions.php в нем параметры name, category, title и т.д.

Мне нужно выйти за пределы этих файлов и чтоб расширения инициализировались в самом плагине, чтоб, если обновится плагин элементора мои доработки не были стерты.
Такое ощущение что это никто, никогда не делал. Информации 0.
Каким образом мне единственный файл плагина запустить и чтоб он работал? Спасибо

Comment: Ну вообще имеет смысл написать плагин расширений для элементора с 0, а не пытаться дорабатывать какой-то существующий, внося правки в его фйлы, это так не работает. Если я Вас верно понял.

Comment: Не суть. Я посмотрел как устроен плагин от самого элементор. Там 20 строк от силы и они все практически по документации. Название расширения, имя и сам паблик что видит пользователь. Я плохо ориентируюсь в терминах. Мне нужно этот плагин 1. Инициализировать. Чтоб он работал и внедрить в формы элементора.чтобы добавив форму я мог свое кастомное поле вывести. Выше написал где они привязываться. Но не знаю как через хуки или что то ещё их саязать. В интернете полно информации о создании плагина. А как свое поле в уже готовый добавить. Вот в чем вопрос

Comment: Ну через хуки, все верно, все зависит от того, где конкретно это поле должно отображаться и что делать

Comment: В стандартной форме элементора. Форма обратной связи которая. Мне надо свое кастомное поле туда добавить

Comment: Поле должно быть в самом сайдбаре где идет редактирование контента и заполнение настроек или это должно быть кастомное поле именно самой контактной формы. Не уверен что ясно изъяснился

Comment: Да. Выше. В самом вопросе есть 2 пункта. Они отвечают за внедрение кастомного поля в саму форму. Но проблема в том что эти настройки находятся в самом плагине элементора. А мне надо эти настройки или привязки. Как угодно можно назвать. Без них не отображается моё собственное поле в выборе полей формы. А как кастомно через свой плагин подключить. Нет информации.

Comment: @Максим, все верно, информации крайне мало. Даже на https://code.elementor.com/ - информация есть, но примеров мало. Более того, сами разработки пишут пример использования на сайте одним способом, а в своих плагинах пишут иначе. Сам сейчас пишу под себя, **приходится копаться в чужих плагинах**. Ранее уже писал два плагина для себя и под свои нужды, а тут понадобился перехват событий, в результате - раскуриваю третий день. Разработчики у кого есть, что позаимствовать пишут так, что бы ты быстро не разобрался и не смог скопипастить. ТИПА: вывод строки - объявляют 8 классов и 20 файлов.

Comment: Вот тут есть примеры как создать свой плагин под Elementor и как разные элементы использовать, а так же выводить в админке или фронтэнде то, что создаёшь: https://developers.elementor.com/